# Rails + Devise + Angular2: аутентификация

Tags: ruby-on-rails, безопасность, devise, csrf, angular2

У меня просто огромное количество вопросов... Но перед этим нужно описать, что собственно происходит.

**Преамбула**

Я пытаюсь научить Angular2 авторизироваться в Rails 5 beta 3 приложении. При этом Rails работает в режиме API. Как я понимаю, для того, чтобы Devise работал в режиме API, нужен gem `devise_token_auth`. Гем я установил и настроил, но вот после этого начались проблемы:

**Unpermitted parameters: user, session**

Первое, что я попробовал сделать после настройки, послать простой POST запрос и посмотреть, что произойдёт. А произошло следующее:

```
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as *json*
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"demo", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "session"=>{"user"=>{"username"=>"demo", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
Unpermitted parameters: user, session
  Rendered devise_token_auth/sessions/create.json (0.2ms)
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 18ms (Views: 3.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

И вот с этого момента я немного не понимаю, с каких это пор я должен прописывать `permit` для параметров, которые `ActionController::ParamsWrapper` создаёт динамически в качестве обёртки? Более того:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in) do |user_params|
  user_params.permit(:user, :session)
end
```

ничего не меняет. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным ранее?

**Authentication header**

Покопавшись в документации в поисках решения проблемы я нашёл другую:

> The authentication information should be included by the client in the headers of each request. The headers follow the RFC 6750 Bearer Token format

Т.е. в заголовке запроса должны быть следующие данные:

```
"access-token": "wwwww",
"token-type":   "Bearer",
"client":       "xxxxx",
"expiry":       "yyyyy",
"uid":          "zzzzz"
```

В AngularJS они генерировались модулем `ng-token-auth`, но как мне сгенерировать их посредством Angular2, у которого данного модуля нет?

---

Подводя промежуточный итог (потому что чувствую я, после этих проблем я наткнусь на их ещё большее количество), вот список моих вопросов:

- Как исправить `unpermitted parameters: user, session` в `devise_token_auth`?
- Как сгенерировать `access-token`?
- Как высчитать `expiry` и есть ли "rails-way" для времени жизни токена?
- Что следует писать в `client`? Раз уж этот идентификатор позволяет пользователю одновременно авторизироваться с нескольких устройств, то как он должен выглядить? Что туда следует записать?

---

- Какие данные следует возвращать клиенту после авторизации (помимо `200`)?
- Какие ещё подводные камни могут меня ждать при попытке авторизироваться через Rails API?

---

**UPD**

Вот запрос, который я шлю:

```
private _user_session_url = 'auth/sign_in';

login (username: string, password: string) : Observable<User> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password });
    // TODO: generate header data.
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'json'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

    return this.http.post(this._user_session_url, body, options)
        .map((data: any) => data.json())
        .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

Как видите, `session` в теле запроса нет. Его создаёт [ActionController::ParamsWrapper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html)

В подтверждение привожу Request Payload:

```
{"username":"demo","password":"123"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [краткой документации](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#usage-tldr) к `devise_token_auth` (DTA) `POST /sign_in` принимает только параметры `email` и `password` **прямо в корне**. То есть, параметры должны выглядеть так:

```
{
  "email": "foo@example.com",
  "password": "bar"
}
```

Никакой вложенности. Не надо дополнительно настраивать санитайзер и придумывать ненужные ключи.

---

А теперь ответ **разом на все** оставшиеся вопросы:

`Token-Type`, `Access-Token`, `Client` и `Expiry`.

> В AngularJS они генерировались модулем `ng-token-auth`

Нет, они генерируются **сервером**, клиент ничем умным не занимается. Хранятся они в БД (в частично искажённом, но проверяемом виде, как пароли), а обмен ими происходит с помощью **заголовков**. `/sign_in` возвращает все интересующие заголовки. Все эти значения вы просто будете передавать туда-сюда (и обновлять, ведь по умолчанию после каждого отдельного запроса токен меняется).

Кроме, разве что, `Expiry`, значением которого можно следить, "когда токен отвалится и потребует обновления", что можно использовать для выкидывания на форму входа.

Пользоваться DTA без `ng-token-auth` можно, но прежде чем за это браться, стоит прочесть документацию к используемым методам.

---

<sub>Я пользовался этим гемом ранее и **не** рекомендую его для случаев, где важна настраиваемость принимаемых и отдаваемых этой системой данных, потому что расширяемость гема близка к нулю.</sub>

Comment: Можете предложить какие-нибудь альтернативы этому гему?

Comment: @Виктор боюсь, что нет. Если от него интересует только аутентификация, он не доставит больших проблем, но если интересуют ещё и запросы с ответами определённой формы (в соответствии с некоей спецификацией, например), то заставить этот гем эту форму соблюдать -- **боль**. Но это редко надо.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне кроме аутентификации на данном этапе от него ничего и не нужно. Изменение тела запроса исправило `Unpermitted parameter: user`, но `Unpermitted parameter: session` до сих пор висит, а так же при попытке авторизации всё ещё возвращается `401`

Comment: @Виктор так а зачем вы этот параметр шлёте, где он в документации-то? Только `email` и `password`, нету никакого `user`.

Comment: я свою ошибку понял и `user` удалил. Но `session` создаётся не мной (см. UPD) и из-за него появляется `Unpermitted parameter: session`

Comment: @Виктор откуда уверенность, что он делается сервером? Проверьте в консоли браузера.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38584/discussion-between--and-d-side).